# Scheduled Actions cron not working in odoo 9?

Tags: python, odoo-9

Scheduled Actions cron not working in odoo 9. I have version odoo 9 setup and 20 database created on that setup. From 20 database, scheduled Cron not worked in 5 database. I cleared the cache using **invalid_all()** method. Still it's not working.

Also increase the

```
max_cron_thread upto 4
```

and restart the postgresql and odoo, but still it's not working. When i am checking log of Postgresql, then i got an error in log i.e.

```
unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction in odoo
```

I also try to resolve this, but i am not getting an appropriate solution. if you have any idea, please share with me, to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After i restart cronjob or run Schedular cron from backend, it works fine for me.
For run cron in terminal. Open odoo shell or python shell. Then use below command.

```
>>from openerp.addons import base
>>import logging
>>logging.basicConfig()
>>base.ir.ir_cron.ir_cron._acquire_job('database-name')
```

Some time it take 30 second for start, so please be patient.